# Win32 API call to select item in locked drop down

Tags: c#, winapi

I have an application that finds all the elements of a desktop application and interacts with that application just fine. The exception is when the control is a combo box (drop down) that the User cannot type in.

We are currently using the following code to interact with the drop down:

```
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, strValue);
```

Is there another API call or message parameter (like CB_SETCURSEL = 0x014E) that I am missing that would actually Select the strValue of the drop down's item collection?

Comment: CB_SELECTSTRING perhaps although it sounds a bit iffy.

Comment: That was it ... We use Send Message with the CB_SELECTSTRING value and it worked beautifully. Thank you!